# Show captured image in ImageView fails with back camera

Tags: android, image, camera

I developed an app in which the user can capture an image either from camera or gallery. For that, the user can click on the imageview, then a dialog shows up and the user can choose to capture from camera or gallery.

If the user chooses to capture the image from gallery or with the front camera then it works fine and the captured image shows up in the imageview. But if the user chooses the back camera and takes the photo and return back to activity, then the image does not show up in the imageview at all.

Here my full source code:

```
public class PostActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.post);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        ab = getActionBar();

        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                show(); //here the dialog box is called, to choose the capture option
            }
        });

        image.setTag(null);
        captureImageInitialization();
    }


    private void show() {

        dialog.show();
    }


    private void captureImageInitialization() {

        final Item[] items = {
                new Item("Camera", R.drawable.ic_action_camera_dark),
                new Item("Gallery", R.drawable.ic_action_collection),

        };

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1, items) {

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                // User super class to create the View
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                // Put the image on the TextView
                tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        items[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

                // Add margin between image and text (support various screen
                // densities)
                int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

                return v;
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Take Image from ...");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);


                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }

        });
        dialog = builder.create();

    }

    public static class Item {
        public final String text;
        public final int icon;

        public Item(String text, Integer icon) {
            this.text = text;
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return text;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:

                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                imagepath = getPath(mImageCaptureUri);

                BitmapFactory.Options options0 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options0.inSampleSize = 2;
                options0.inScaled = false;
                options0.inDither = false;
                options0.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath, options0);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                ExifInterface exif;
                int m = 0;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(imagepath);

                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);

                    if (orientation == 6) {
                        m = 90;

                    } else if (orientation == 3) {
                        m = 180;

                    } else if (orientation == 8) {
                        m = 270;

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                matrix.postRotate(m);
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                        bmp.getHeight(), matrix, false);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos0 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                image.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmp));
                image.setTag("1");
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos0);
                byte[] imageBytes0 = baos0.toByteArray();
                krt1 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes0, Base64.DEFAULT);
                break;

            case PICK_FROM_FILE:

                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                imagepath = getPath(mImageCaptureUri);

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
                options.inScaled = false;
                options.inDither = false;
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath, options);

                ExifInterface exif2;
                int m2 = 0;
                try {
                    exif2 = new ExifInterface(imagepath);

                    int orientation = exif2.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);

                    if (orientation == 6) {
                        m2 = 90;

                    } else if (orientation == 3) {
                        m2 = 180;

                    } else if (orientation == 8) {
                        m2 = 270;

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix();
                matrix2.postRotate(m2);
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                        bmp.getHeight(), matrix2, false);

                image.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmp));
                image.setTag("1");
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos2);
                byte[] imageBytes2 = baos2.toByteArray();
                krt1 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes2, Base64.DEFAULT);
                break;
            }

    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            ;
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;

    }
```

This issue with the back camera is really weird, because I never had such an issue. (BTW tested on Samsung device). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code for taking the image from front facing camera -

```
public class CameraController {

    private Context context;

    private boolean hasCamera;

    private Camera camera;
    private int cameraId;

    public CameraController(Context c){
        context = c.getApplicationContext();

        if(context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            cameraId = getFrontCameraId();

            if(cameraId != -1){
                hasCamera = true;
            }else{
                hasCamera = false;
            }
        }else{
            hasCamera = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasCamera(){
        return hasCamera;
    }

    public void getCameraInstance(){
        camera = null;

        if(hasCamera){
            try{
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                prepareCamera();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                hasCamera = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void takePicture(){
        if(hasCamera){
            camera.takePicture(null,null,mPicture);
        }
    }

    public void releaseCamera(){
        if(camera != null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    private int getFrontCameraId(){
        int camId = -1;
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();

        for(int i = 0;i < numberOfCameras;i++){
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i,ci);
            if(ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
                camId = i;
            }
        }

        return camId;
    }

    private void prepareCamera(){
        SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(context);

        try{
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        camera.startPreview();

        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setJpegQuality(100);

        camera.setParameters(params);  
    }

    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

            if(pictureFile == null){
                Log.d("TEST", "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
                return;
            }

            try{
                Log.d("TEST","File created");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.d("TEST","File not found: "+e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e){
                Log.d("TEST","Error accessing file: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    private File getOutputMediaFile(){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"MyCameraApp");

        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if(!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if(!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath()+File.separator+"IMG_"+timeStamp+".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: hello mr. Tamrakar  I have issues with taking the image with the back camera. Front camera works well with my code.

Comment: Taking image with back camera is pretty simple. You can use intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE which you are already using. Can you tell me what problem you are facing.

Comment: ok I could figure something out: When I take the photo with the back camera in landscape then it appears in the imageview. But when I take the image in potrait with back camera then it doesn't appear. And my layout file has  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. But why this happens?

Comment: The reason that onCreate() is called is because when you do call the camera activity during the portrait orientation, it will change the orientation and destroy your previous activity. After finishing the onActivityResult(), your activity will be re-created.

Comment: ah okay that make sense. But what would your suggestion be to solve this issue? I removed `android:screenOrientation="potrait"`, but it seems like the activity is still re-created.

Comment: Add this - android:configChanges="orientation" in manifest activity tag, this might solve your issue.

Comment: I added this: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`. So easy and it took me almost one day to solve it. Thank you very much Mr. Tamrakar!

Comment: One last question: Let's say the user has another camera application installed on his device. So he can choose between the regular cam app (that is already installed on device) and another cam app (e.g. named powercam; available on play store). But when I choose the powercam to capture image, then the app crashes after capturing and saving. Did you had such a case?